# Jenkins build trigger configuration getting lost

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the

> Build after other projects are built

feature of Jenkins. I am using Jenkins ver 2.73.2 and whenever I go to

> Configure job -> Build Triggers

and specify my projects, the configuration does not get saved. There is no save button so when I navigate to another page the configuration gets lost.

I am using JenkinsFile in all projects to build it so this is the first thing I am doing from the UI.

Couldn't find a proper solution to this issue anywhere.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I'm having the same issue?

Answer (score -1):

[image: Build Triggers Image]

- Try to restart your jenkins.
- Possibly you my have harmed you jenkins folder in program files.
- Please try to upgrade your jenkins

Comment: I am using Jenkins as a service. The save button can be disabled from the administrator. One reason of not having the save button is that I am using JenkinsFile for the configuration/build.